# Configurable Swatches Magento not working

Tags: magento

Related to this guide I have updgraded our store to Magento 1.9.1:
[Configurable Swatches Guide for Magento...](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ee1141-ce191-configurable-swatches)

The problem is that the thumbnails and color swatches are not sowing up. In the system.log there is this error:

```
2015-01-16T16:56:39+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: product_id  in /magento/app/code/core/Mage/ConfigurableSwatches/Helper/Mediafallback.php on line 281
```

This is the code snippet:

```
    foreach ($mediaGallery['images'] as $mediaGalleryImage) {
        if ($mediaGalleryImage['product_id'] == $product->getId()) {
            $newMediaGalleryImages[] = $mediaGalleryImage;
        } else {
            $configurableImages[] = $mediaGalleryImage;
        }
    }
```

When I check the array I cannot find $mediaGalleryImage['product_id']. I'm not sure whether it went something wrong with the upgrade or if it's a magento bug. I test it with the rwd theme.

Answer (score 3):

I came across this exact problem, in my case it was a third party extension called MageWorx SeoSuite (version 3.13.0).
The problem I had was the gallery images weren't showing on the product detail when configurable swatches were enabled.
Upgrading to the latest version as of this post (3.14.2) still did not fix it.

I tracked it down to the 'loadGallery' method in the class 
`MageWorx_XSitemap_Model_Catalog_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Attribute_Backend_Media`
within the MageWorx_XSitemap module. This breaks the configurable swatches feature.

I had to comment it out for the time being in the modules config.xml:

```
        <catalog_resource_eav_mysql4>
            <rewrite>
                <!-- <product_attribute_backend_media>MageWorx_XSitemap_Model_Catalog_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Attribute_Backend_Media</product_attribute_backend_media> -->
            </rewrite>
        </catalog_resource_eav_mysql4>
```

So, check any class rewrites.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hey thank you for that. I will check it asap and give a feedback.

Answer (score 0):

as what MageMechanic.com said,
if you are using xsitemap and you have the following rewrite:

```
<catalog_resource_eav_mysql4>
            <rewrite>
                <product_attribute_backend_media>MageWorx_XSitemap_Model_Catalog_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Attribute_Backend_Media</product_attribute_backend_media>
            </rewrite>
        </catalog_resource_eav_mysql4>
```

go to the class MageWorx_XSitemap_Model_Catalog_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Attribute_Backend_Media , and update loadGalary function to be as following:

```
public function loadGallery($product, $object)
{
    $eventObjectWrapper = new Varien_Object(
        array(
            'product' => $product,
            'backend_attribute' => $object
        )
    );
    Mage::dispatchEvent(
        $this->_eventPrefix . '_load_gallery_before',
        array('event_object_wrapper' => $eventObjectWrapper)
    );

    if ($eventObjectWrapper->hasProductIdsOverride()) {
        $productIds = $eventObjectWrapper->getProductIdsOverride();
    } else {
        $productIds = array($product->getId());
    }

    $connection  = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
    $tablePrefix = (string) Mage::getConfig()->getTablePrefix();
    $result      = $connection->fetchAll("
                SELECT `main`.`value_id`, `main`.`value` AS `file`, `main`.`entity_id` AS `product_id`, `value`.`label`, `value`.`position`,
                    `value`.`disabled`, `default_value`.`label` AS `label_default`, `default_value`.`position` AS `position_default`,
                    `default_value`.`disabled` AS `disabled_default`
                FROM `" . $tablePrefix . "catalog_product_entity_media_gallery` AS `main`
                LEFT JOIN `" . $this->getTable(self::GALLERY_VALUE_TABLE) . "` AS `value`
                    ON main.value_id=value.value_id
                    AND value.store_id=" . (int) $product->getStoreId() . "
                LEFT JOIN `" . $this->getTable(self::GALLERY_VALUE_TABLE) . "` AS `default_value`
                    ON main.value_id=default_value.value_id AND default_value.store_id=0
                WHERE (main.attribute_id = '" . $object->getAttribute()->getId() . "')
                    AND (main.entity_id in ('" . implode("','", $productIds). "'))
                ORDER BY IF(value.position IS NULL, default_value.position, value.position) ASC");

    $this->_removeDuplicates($result);
    return $result;
}
```

This way you will keep the benefit from this plugin and same time will get the default magento color swatcher :)
engoy coding ;)